# Is it possible to add virtuoso as a storage provider in Jena-Fuseki?

Tags: java, jena, virtuoso, tdb

I am trying to set up virtuoso as a storage provider service inside Jena-Fuseki config.ttl file is it possible to add this service as RDF database to Fuseki, is it a right way or I must have to add virtuoso.jena.driver Packege inside Fuseki-Server.jar file?
I am asking this question because When we are using Apache-Jena TDB service as a database to our RDF data we always include this java class from Apache-Jena as given below.

#TDB
[] ja:loadClass "com.hp.hpl.jena.tdb.TDB" .

I just need a clear answer and if service without includeing packege is possible then may be give me that service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it is possible to connect virtuoso or indeed any other system to Fuseki.  All SPARQL services run over an abstraction that can be extended.  That extension can be from basic triple access to the other system taking over full responsibility for all SPARQL operations.

Jena does not provide system-dependent connectors to other systems.  Such connectors need to come from the system being incorporated because how the connector works internally will reflect the nature of the system.

Have a look at what Virtuoso provides in OpenLinks "Virtuoso Jena Provider".

Comment: Is this the right way to do it just a blueprint?
[] ja:loadClass "virtuoso.jena.driver.VirtDataset" .
jdbc:VirtDataset  rdfs:subClassOf  ja:GraphBase .
jdbc:VirtGraph    rdfs:subClassOf  ja:GraphBase .

Comment: That is a question for OpenLink.  All ja:loadClass does is load the class - the class itself is responsible for wiring itself into Jena.